# How do I configure ninject to return a dynamic proxy of T?

Tags: .net, ninject, dynamic-proxy

I have a class `UserModel` I want to proxy it for caching. So i've set up `public class UserModelCached:DynamicProxy<UserModel>` via http://greenicicleblog.com/2010/02/21/piece-of-proxy-cake/

Now I want Ninject to still be able to create a `UserModel` but when a `UserModel` is asked for it returns the proxy instead.

Everything I can think of seems it would result in a stack overflow because ninject would ask how to create a UserModel to create the proxy; the internal dictionary for where to get one would point to the same method that gets the dynamic proxy instead. I don't want to hardcode the parameters of the actual `UserModel` class.

Is this possible **without creating an interface** and adding it to both classes?

Comment: Have you looked at Ninject.Extensions.Interception ?

Comment: I have not, can you provide some insight or a summary answer about how it works or would work?

Comment: No; sorry. However my knowledge of Ninject suggests to me 1) the cited extension is doing something similar (so it might serve as a start or may even be what you're looking for) 2) pretty sure the exact thing doesnt exist OOTB (which is why it was a comment not an answer) 3) The Ninject codebase is Very approachable and has extremely Clean tests illustrating every possible combination of things that the thing is expected to be able to do (Wild Guess as to how you do it: I think you'll be able to do it as a short Component that you'll add to your Kernel on creation)

Comment: All of that is aside from the fact that the likelihood is that the exact thing Ninject.Extensions.Interception provides is very likely to be __directly__ what you need